# Python Request Library 1.11 InvalidURL: URL has an invalid label

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I am getting the exception InvalidURL: URL has an invalid label for the URL which has underscore in it.I  encountered this issue for 2.11.1. The URL looks like this https://p-q-r-dev.appspot.com/n_m. Is there anything wrong with this URI although the same thing was working fine before. Thanks!

```
return requests.get(request_url)
lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 294, in prepare
self.prepare_url(url, params)
lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 363, in prepare_url
raise InvalidURL('URL has an invalid label.')
InvalidURL: URL has an invalid label.
```

Comment: Does the url exist when you access it on a regular browser?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes!

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace?

Comment: @DustinIngram added the stack trace. i read somewhere that it might be related to authorization parameters. if you know anything more on that please let me know as the requests.get() accepts authorization parameter.

Comment: Are you sure that `https://p-q-r-dev.appspot.com/n_m` is the exact url? This error is raised when the URL contains non-ASCII characters, or starts with an `*`: https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/bedd9284c9646e50c10b3defdf519d4ba479e2c7/requests/models.py#L392-L402

Comment: @DustinIngram yes its the exact url.